# MVC and Bootstrap Tabs - Can't display data in Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I needed to have a View in my application that has 2 tabs. After struggling, I came up with the following with Bootstap Tabs and Partial Views:

```
<div id="tabs">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
            <li class="active">
                <a href="#OptinStatus" data-toggle="tab">Optin Status</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#OptiHistory" data-toggle="tab">Optin History</a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content">
            <div class="tab-pane active" id="OptinStatus">
                @Html.Partial("_OptinStatus")
            </div>
            <div class="tab-pane" id="OptiHistory">
                @Html.Partial("_OptinHistory")
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

As long as I do this in my Results action, I can display the two tabs side by side and switch:

```
 public ActionResult Results(OptinStatusViewModel viewModel)
        {
                        // return RedirectToAction("OptInStatus");
            return View();
        }
```

The problem is now that I want to do some processing in the controller and display the results in the Partial View. so I switched the above to:

```
return RedirectToAction("OptInStatus");
```

That Action Method is supposed to be for the 1st partial view:

```
 public ActionResult OptInStatus(OptinStatusViewModel viewModel)
        {
            HarmonyOperation harmonyoper = new HarmonyOperation();

            ListProfileData res = new ListProfileData();

            string listid = "60285206-7c9e-4af3-a0c4-0a69ec8d4bb4";  // Preferences Master List
            string email = (string) TempData["User"];

            string customerKey = Tools.GetCustomerKeyByEmail(email);

            res = harmonyoper.GetProfileFromListByCustomerKey(listid, customerKey);

            IDictionary<string, string> profileData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            // Found record in LIST for email
            if (res != null)
            {
                profileData = Tools.ListKeyValueToDictionary(res.attributes);

                //Check existence of this email
            }

            return View("_OptinStatus");
```

The problem when I do this is I get a new View that displays the "contents" of the Partial View instead of that Partial View in its tab. How can I get data to my partial view?

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a View from your controller, when you should be returning PartialView.

So instead of:

```
return View("_OptinStatus");
```

You do:

```
return PartialView("_OptinStatus", model); //model is not required
```

And you should get this model in the actual view "_OptinStatus", not in the "main view".

**An example of using seperate partial models:**

Controllers:

```
public ActionResult Results()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult OptInStatus()
{
    return PartialView("_OptinStatus");
}

... etc
```

Results-view:

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="OptinStatus">
        @Html.Action("_OptinStatus")
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="OptiHistory">
        @Html.Action("_OptinHistory")
    </div>
</div>
```

_OptinStatus-partialView:

```
@model OptinStatusModel
<div>My partial for Status</div>
```

_OptinHistory-partialView:

```
@model OptinHistoryModel
<div>My partial for History</div>
```

**The same example using viewModel for both partials:**

Controllers:

```
public ActionResult Results(OptinStatusViewModel viewModel)
{
    return View("Results", viewModel);
}
```

Results-view:

```
@model OptinStatusViewModel
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="OptinStatus">
            @Html.Partial("_OptinStatus", Model.OptionStatusModel)
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="OptiHistory">
            @Html.Partial("_OptinHistory", Model.OptionHistoryModel)
        </div>
    </div>
```

_OptinStatus-partialView:

```
@model OptinStatusModel
<div>My partial for Status</div>
```

_OptinHistory-partialView:

```
@model OptinHistoryModel
<div>My partial for History</div>
```

**My prefered solution:**

jQuery, included in _layouts

```
$(".partialContents").each(function(index, item) {
    var url = $(item).data("url");
    if (url && url.length > 0) {
        $(item).load(url);
    }
});
```

Now, instead of using Razor to render the views, you just use a div (and ajax through the code above):

```
<div class="partialContents" data-url="/Home/OptInStatus">
```

HomeController will get hit on action "OptInStatus".

Comment: I thought when I did that it created a new PartialView on it's own page. And I have to do the processing of getting the results from the partial view. Also I can return one PartialView not 2 for the two tabs. How do I figure out which one I am on?

Comment: Yes, this displays the contents of the PartialView only on a new otherwise blank view. No tabs anymore

Comment: Well, you can do either, but not both. Either have a ViewModel keep together the 2 partials, or seperate them in to 2 partialViews (each with their own set of actions and models). You're not returning the PartialView to the "Results" view, but to the "_OptinStatus" view. Then in the other PartialView you return "_OptinHistory".

Comment: But the rest of Results is gone. No tabs anymore, just the contents  of _OptinStatus on an empty page.

Comment: After your updated example, I don't anymore a Results View with its two tabs. I get a new View with just the contents of _OptinStatus. I have to display the results view with the two partials. Is this in the HttpGet Action method of the Contoller?

Comment: Please show the Controller for the Results action method and _OptinStatus action method.

Comment: Are those HttpGet action methods or POST? I can't seem to have an GET Post method for OptinStatus method.

Comment: It's whatever you choose it to be. Adding [HttpPost] above the controller definition makes it a "Post", adding [HttpGet] (or leaving it blank) makes it a get. In other words they are GETs in my examples.

Comment: Well then how does the Action Method OptInStatus get called? Who calls it? It doesn't get called automatically when the Partial is rendered.

Comment: It doesn't get called from @html.Partial when I do <div class="tab-pane active" id="OptinStatus">
                @Html.Partial("_OptinStatus")

Comment: True, it does not get called for Html.Partial. In that case your "Results" action would be called, to render the main view. If you want to hit "OptInStatus" for the load, use Html.Action("OptInStatus") or Html.RenderAction instead.

Comment: @user2471435 I added yet another example, of what I use personally.